# Is there a way to run Xcode 6 and 7 side-by-side?

Tags: macos, xcode

I want to keep Xcode 6 for now, as my apps have been built and tested with that. I also have Xcode 7 Beta 6, and I’d like to upgrade that to the release version of Xcode 7.

The App Store just has an Update button for Xcode 7, and I suspect it would upgrade my 6 to 7, but I can’t find this documented anywhere.

So, will the App Store Xcode 7 Upgrade replace my Xcode 6? If so, is there some other way to get the release version of Xcode 7?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easier: Rename the existing Xcode ("Xcode 6"), then install the new Xcode. Alternatively, but the current Xcode in another folder ("/Applications/Xcode 6"). For many versions now, Xcode has carried the important stuff in the app bundle, including frameworks. There's no problem have the two versions on your system. And this is precisely how beta tester test new versions—they don't delete the current one, the beta version simply has a different name ("Xcode-beta").

PS—Use the xcode-select command to switch the command-line tools to the current version you're using. Do "man xcode-select" in Terminal to view the command doc.

Comment: Accepting your answer because it's better than mine and you mentioned xcode-select -s.

Comment: I was using both Xcode 6 and 7 by this way from about 2 weeks. Unfortunately it seems the old Xcode (renamed Xcode_6.4.app) has been removed today from the Application directory. I'm not able to retrieve it just after Xcode 7 to have been launched. I don't know why. Does someone meet this issue too?

Comment: Same thing happened to me. My renamed XCode6 disappeared. So this answer does not work. :-(

Comment: @skypecakes don't just rename, put it in a folder as mentioned in the answer

Comment: Maybe update the answer to remove the "Easier" option which can allow XCode6 to get deleted. Or somehow mention why one would choose the "Alternative" method.

Answer (score 6):

Figured out how (not if it’s advisable) to do this:

1. [Downloaded Xcode 7](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/?name=Xcode) (instead of using Upgrade from App Store option).
2. Opened the downloaded dmg and dragged the `Xcode.app` to my desktop.
3. Renamed this `Xcode.app` to `Xcode-7.app`
4. Dropped this `Xcode-7.app` into my `Applications/` directory.

Comment: @JakeGould One version of Xcode is used by the command line tools, and you can switch between them w/ smthg like: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-7.app

Answer (score 0):

Switching with `xcode-select` stopped to work for me with Xcode 7.1 (concurrent with Xcode 6.4).
After running Xcode 7.1, Xcode 6.4 failed with a strange error relating to storyboards.

The root cause is that Xcode tries to use the iOS 9.x simulator at compile time.
The only way I know by now to cope with this, is to delete the simulator runtime for iOS 9.x.
You can find the runtime here:

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
```

You can always get it back from trash or re-install from Xcode 7.x